# If statement doesn't print desired value

Tags: python

It should print out stuff stored in generator variable if raw input was 1, but its not doing that, its executing else statement even if I write 1.

```
from random import randint

print('1. Generate again.')
print('2. Close')
x = raw_input('Pick your selection 1 or 2: ')

if x == 1:
    generator = (randint(1000000000000000,999000000000000009))
    print generator
else:
    print 'bye'
```

Comment: Yeah lol, I forgot to add ' '. thanks bud

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're comparing a string (what was input) with an int. Try `if x == '1'` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I'm stupid for not seeing that.

Answer (score 2):

Turn's answers is a good one, but there is an alternative way to do this by using `int()`. The built-in function `int()` treats the string as an int.

```
from random import randint

print('1. Generate again.')
print('2. Close')
x = raw_input('Pick your selection 1 or 2: ')

if int(x) == 1:
    generator = (randint(1000000000000000,999000000000000009))
    print generator
else:
    print 'bye'
```

Comment: You can indeed do it that way but you should be prepared for `int` to throw an exception if the user didn't enter an integer. I think it is simpler to just compare strings.